# Android values.xml <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: android

This is my code for my values.xml file. I am running into difficulty getting my project to run because apparently there is an error with this file on line 2 column 4 according to this error:

```
C:\Users\16094\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2163979b6567cda52ae0ebf1a205491d\fragment-1.3.4\res\values\values.xml:2:4: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

This is the code for my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <declare-styleable name="Fragment">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:id"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FragmentContainerView">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I already read through this but I could not find anything wrong with my file: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources

Comment: Mind sharing the file name and location ? Have you tried separating `item` and `declare-styleable` into different files ?

Comment: @JonZarate I attempted to run the app without the `<declare-styleable>` tags in the XML file and I still had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are no errors in XML fragment you shared. I know the sample you're playing with, the error caused by wrong ID resource definition in ids.xml

```
<item name="button" type="id">Button</item>
```

But according to [documentaion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id) ID definition takes no value. So the fix is:

```
<item name="button" type="id" />
```